# What does core.js file in Jquery source do?

Tags: jquery

Could anyone explain to me what is the use of core.js file in jquery source folder?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> core.js is responsible for defining the jQuery **namespace**, as well as
>   the **prototype** for jQuery objects. -  [How jQuery Works - An Introduction](https://benmccormick.org/2015/06/08/how-jquery-works-an-introduction)

This below may also be quite useful or at least help you get a better understanding, but to be honest the quote above i would argue is sufficient enough knowledge on the core.js file.

> It’s no longer maintained with newer versions, but a few years ago Rob
>   Flaherty created an annotated version of jQuery 1.6’s source.

[jQuery v1.6 Annotated Source Docs](http://robflaherty.github.io/jquery-annotated-source/)

[Core.js Annotated Source](http://robflaherty.github.io/jquery-annotated-source/docs/01-core.html)